# django compressor creating a lot of cache files

Tags: django, caching, static, django-compressor

The servers are behind load balancer, and for whatever reason compressor created tens of thousands of cache files in `/static/CACHE/js/` and `/static/CACHE/css/`

The only setting in my settings.py is: `COMPRESS_ENABLED = True`

Is there a setting I am missing to clean up the CACHE files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think I have found the culprit, there is a piece of template generated javascript code included inside the compress tag, causing compressor to keep generating new cache files.

eg.

```
{% compress js %}
    <script src="...">
    <script src="...">
    var data = {{ context_data_var }};
{% endcompress %}
```

Comment: What piece javascript is it?