# django-compressor writing new files in collect_static/CACHE on every request

Tags: django, nginx, memcached, django-compressor, collectstatic

I've a django website set up using django-compressor + memcached.
Not sure when it started, but I'm finding new css and js files in `.../collect_static/CACHE/css` and `.../collect_static/CACHE/js` every minute, like `output.2fde5b60eff0.css`.

I use `django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage`.

I have no clue if this is normal, or happening because of some misconfiguration. But in every few days, I need to clean the server because of this.

Any suggestions what is going on here?

**Update:** It seems to be happening because of template variables inside css and js code, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13601250) answer, but as I've a lot of such variables, I still don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the underlying reason.
It is not actually the presence of template variables like `{{context_data_var}}` within compressed code.

It is the presence of any such variables the **values of which change on each request**.
I had two such instances:

1. Storage keys for the third party storage service (such as Google or Amazon)
2. csrf tokens used in various ajax requests

For 1. above, I simply moved such code outside compress.

For 2., the solution is slightly involved. I had to move away from using `{{csrf_token}}`. Django explains it in detail [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false). We need to use the `csrftoken` cookie instead of the variable `{{csrf_token}}`, and django sets this cookie if there is at least one `{% csrf_token %}` in the template. I had one luckily in my base template, so the cookie was already getting set for me. I also had the `getCookie()` function defined for all pages.

Thus, I was able to get rid of the issue explained in my question.